# Order by number of entries linq

Tags: c#, linq-to-entities

I'm trying to filter and sort data from a table based on the number of entries in one column

```
|  OrderID  | DateOrdered  | EnteredById |  OtherData  |  OtherData2  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1       |  2/2/2017    |     3       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
|   2       |  2/2/2017    |     4       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
|   3       |  2/3/2017    |     4       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
|   4       |  2/4/2017    |     3       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
|   5       |  2/4/2017    |     4       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
|   6       |  2/6/2017    |     5       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
```

This is a C# project, there is a working model set up for the table (Orders)
I need to use Linq with Entity to return an array of objects, the whole row, sorted by the number of orders entered by each EnteredById and only where there has been more than one entry by that EnteredById.

In the end, it should be:

`|  OrderID  | DateOrdered  | EnteredById |  OtherData  |  OtherData2  |
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    |   2       |  2/2/2017    |     4       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
    |   3       |  2/3/2017    |     4       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
    |   5       |  2/4/2017    |     4       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
    |   4       |  2/4/2017    |     3       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |
    |   1       |  2/2/2017    |     3       |  asdf       |      sadfsf  |`

The code I've written is an absolute mess so I haven't posted it here.  Does anybody have the secret Linq answer?

Comment: in linq you can do `.OrderBy().ThenBy()`

Comment: I think I misunderstood the question after rereading it sounds like you actually want to get a count of rows(Orders) that share an EnteredById use that count to filter out the orders not made  by a repeat customer (count > 1) then order the remaining rows(Orders) by EnteredById and then OrderId. Is that correct?

Comment: @cholisky did you find the answer

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = objListOrder.GroupBy(o=>o.EnteredById).Where((x,groupid)=> x.Count()>1).SelectMany((x,groupid)=>x).OrderBy(o=>o.EnteredById);
```

Comment: Yep! Sorry it took a couple to get it right, misunderstood the original request.

Comment: Actually it needs to be ordered by count of EnteredById - eg. if EnteredById: 6 entered 5 orders, then those 5 orders would be at the top of the list, EnteredById: 4 enters 3 orders, those 3 orders would be next, and EnteredById: 3 enters two orders, those are last on the list

Comment: @cholisky, there is an OrderBy at the end, although to your point it may need to be OrderByDescending